# Namespace issue with pysaml2 XML canonicalization

Tags: python, xml, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I'm new to SAML and just encountered a problem when using pysaml2 to build an IdP. When creating a signed authn response, the canonicalization algorithm specified in xmldsig/**init**.py is exclusive canonicalization ('http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#') and it will not include declarations for some namespaces which are necessary for some SPs (e.g. namespace xmlns:xs for QNames like in xsi:type="xs:string"). The W3C recommendation specified InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList to handle these cases, but I couldn't find how to do it in pysaml2. There's a similar issue here:
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49710

Is there a solution for pysaml2? Either include these namespaces, or just remove all these xsi:type="xs:string".

Thank you!

Comment: Running into the same issue. Thanks for writing down your findings.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in the pysaml2 4.3.0 release, available on [pypi/pysaml2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysaml2). Also see https://github.com/rohe/pysaml2/pull/336 and https://github.com/rohe/pysaml2/pull/365.